# append a NSString converted from dictionary object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdictionary, nsmutablestring

I have been bothered by this problem for a long time.

I have a NSString which is the received from a RSS parser, I can successfully NSlog it on the screen, but when I try to append it to an existing NSmutablearray, it causes exception.

Here is my code.

```
//mystring is a NSMutableString with some content initialized succesfully

NSString *myDate = [dic objectForKey:@"date"];
NSLog(@"%@ and %@",myString,myDate);
[myString appendString:myDate];
```

until the NSLog, both myDate and myString are printed on screen correctly as I desire, but the appendString line causes error

*[*_NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0*7141a00 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reasons: '-[__NSDate length]: ..........

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `-appendString:` with `myDate`, which isn't a string. It's an `NSDate`. You can't pass it to an API that expects a string. You need to convert it into a string somehow. This is probably best done using `NSDateFormatter`, which gives you full control over how to format your date as a string.

For testing purposes though, you can just replace your last line with `[myString appendString:[myDate description]]` and it should stop crashing.

Comment: Indeed! Just because there was no exception when I initialize the myDate as NSString had fooled me into thinking the dic object date was a NSString, while it was actually a NSDate. Change to NSDate *myDate = [dic objectForKey:@"date"], and use a formatter's stringFromDate, then I can successfully append it. Don't forget to set Dateformat for your formatter, without which it won't work.